If GitHub action overwrites errors, then how to capture all errors in a GitHub Issue?
I would like to capture linting errors into the Issue description that is raised by the end user.
As I have SQL files in my repo, I am using SQLFLUFF. To check validity of GitHub-actions code, I deliberately removed a semicolon in both SQL files. However, what I noticed is I am able to capture only the last error raised. I realized this when I checked the output for "List all .sql files in the repo" step (mentioned below). The error raised in 02 Folder, could have been overwritten by 01 folder.
If that is the case then how to capture error raised in entire repo?
Repo structure:
├── Folder_1/
│   └── ddl_1.sql
├── Folder_2/
│   └── 02_dml_1.sql
└── README.md

YML file:
name: Lint SQL Files

on:
  issues:
    types: [opened]

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      issues: write
      contents: read
      packages: read

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.2.2

      - name: Install SQLFluff
        run: |
          pip install sqlfluff

      - name: Lint all SQL files in the repo
        run: |
          # Run SQLFluff on all .sql files recursively in the repo
          sqlfluff lint --dialect snowflake --write-output sqlfluff_report '.'
          
      - name: List all .sql files in the repo
        if: failure() 
        run: |
          # List all .sql files in the repo to verify they are being detected
          find . -name "*.sql"
          
      - name: Check if there are linting errors and post to GitHub Issue
        if: failure()  # Only run if linting fails
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          ISSUE: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
        run: |
          # Capture SQLFluff JSON output into a variable
          ERROR_LOG=$(cat sqlfluff_report)

          # Check if any errors exist
          if [ -z "$ERROR_LOG" ]; then
            ERROR_LOG="No linting issues found."
          fi

          # Post the error log to the GitHub issue
          gh issue comment $ISSUE --body "SQLFluff found the following issues: $ERROR_LOG"

      - name: Close issue
        if: failure()  # Only run if there are errors
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          REPO: ${{ github.repository }}
          ISSUE: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
        run: |
          # Close the issue and add a comment
          gh issue close --repo "$REPO" --comment "Autoclosing issue $ISSUE due to linting errors."

ddl_1.sql in Folder_1:
DROP TABLE Shippers;
DROP TABLE Sellers
DROP TABLE Employee;

02_dml_1.sql in Folder_2:
DROP TABLE t2

Output from List all .sql files in the repo:
./Folder_2/02_dml_1.sql
./Folder_1/ddl_1.sql

